# What actions gain experience for units?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'd like to try to spread the XP around my group, so that I'm frequently ranking up both my experienced soldiers *and* my new recruits.

I'm pretty sure that I get XP for killing an alien, but are there other actions I can take during a mission to maximize my XP gain?

For instance, this guy, my newly minted Corporal, Marcel Petit:

[image]

He's got a grand total of 1 kill.  He's just made Corporal though, so that's 2 ranks in 4 missions with just one kill on record.  He's not been stunning aliens either (this is so early in the game I haven't researched Arc Throwers yet).  I didn't get him as a quest reward - these four missions are the only ones I've played.

Comment: Kills. Shoot them, commander.

Comment: Are you sure? I think just trying to hit them also nets some xp. I know I've had rookie's rank up without getting a single kill. Although that might be only rookies

Comment: Yeah, I've got some Captains that have 5 kills on record, and I'm certain they haven't been stunning aliens (since they only pack medkits).  There's got to be more to it than what's listed here.

Comment: @agent86 - You're sure these captains aren't ones you've received as mission rewards?

Comment: @SaintWacko, here's an example from my latest game, complete with screenshot.

Comment: I believe everyone that went on a mission gets a chunk of exp just for surviving it. Though I have no actual numbers to back this up, I have seen people that do not have the little white "you get a promotion cross" next to their name on the last turn of a mission suddenly be promoted on the debrief screen.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These are what grant you XP and how much:

1. Alien Kill   30/60*
2. Regular Missions     60/90*
3. Storyline Missions   120/180*
4. Zero KIAs    20
5. Resist Psi Attack    10**
6. Successful Mindfray  20**
7. Successful Mind Inspiration  30**
8. Assist Mind Inspiration  30**
9. Successful Psi Panic     30**

*Additional XPs earned if the soldier has a rank of Lieutenant or  less and kills any of the higher alien ranks (Ethereals, Sectopods,  Elite Mutons, Sectoid Commanders, etc.) during the mission.

**Psionic actions.

Your soldiers have different requirements for promotions:

- Rookie    0
- Squaddie  90
- Corporal  300
- Sergeant  510
- Lieutenant    745
- Captain   1100
- Major     1560
- Colonel   2150
- Psionic*  0
- Specialist    50
- Operative     120

Source: http://ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Soldiers_(EU2012)#Earning_XPs

Comment: Does the 'zero KIA' count civilians (during terror missions) as well?

Comment: No, KIA refers to team mates. So not losing any soldiers on Terror Missions, but losing civilians will give you "No KIA" bonus, but saving all civilians but losing one soldier gives no bonus.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Hello, great work all!

I wanted to let everybody know, you do not have get a kill to level up a soldier!

Melaina did not take any actions during the 4 missions except to hunker down. She did not fire any shots or assist the team in any way.

Also, I'm not sure if capturing aliens will reward the soldier with XP. I'll have check this out later.

Comment: I've just finished a experiment to see if capture aliens alive rewards the soldier with XP. 

The conclusion; Capturing Aliens does NOT provide additional XP for capturing soldier.

In this experiment, I used a Squadi with 2 arch throwers equipped. After she captured 4 aliens, I left her in a corner hunkered down. She did not fire a shot. I used her to capture a total of 12 aliens in 3 missions. After completing the 3rd mission w/o lvl up, I confidently conclude that capturing aliens does not provide XP.

Answer (score 1):

Kills and capturing aliens alive.

Comment: Are you sure capturing aliens gives experience?

Comment: I can confirm that capturing aliens gives XP - I have a solider who is ranking up on 0 kills - he is my Arc Thrower suicide runner :)

Comment: There's more to it than this - see my screenshot.

Answer (score -4):

Your group gets shared XP, so whatever you kill/capture (as EVERY single mission has you killing everything) every member of your group gets XP - this is great for getting two rookies with a group of veterans and levelling them up.

Comment: Not sure about that one -- I've more than once seen the message "<rank> Urist has earned a promotion!" after a successful kill - but *only* the one making the kill or capture. There may be some degree of shared experience but whoever makes the kill definitely gets more.

Comment: I agree with @shadur. There is definitely not 100% shared XP - I'm playing on a difficulty that is too easy for me it seems to I haven't lost a man yet (thoguh a few injuries) and for those first few missions without any injuries they definitely all levelled at different times, etc. I've not really paid attention to what my rookies have done in missions (if I have them I tend to try to let them get a kill if I can to level them though).